# Is a retreating blade stall a problem that can be overcome on dual-rotor helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, flight-dynamics

I know that regular main+tail rotor helicopters stall at higher speeds as the relative airspeed of the retreating blade approaches zero.

I'm curious if coaxial or intermeshing dual-rotor helicopters are affected by the same or a similar problem.

I'm aware that other factors may dominate and impose speed limits on them as well, but I'd like to know if a retreating blade stall is a problem that can be overcome with dual rotors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dual and intermeshing rotors also suffer from retreating blade stall at high forward velocity. But the effect of this is much less dramatic than with a single rotor.

Retreating blade stall causes a loss of lift on one side of the rotor: the single rotor helicopter will start to roll. A helicopter with two rotors that counter-rotate doesn’t experience this rolling moment, only an increase in drag.

Comment: So as I understand it, it can keep flying safely even if its efficiency suffers. Right?

Comment: @edgerunner Right.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that in coaxials, the faster you go the upper retreating blade rises less while the lower advancing blade rises more, eventually leading to a very exciting intersection of the rotor cones?